# SQL How do I select an entity that occurs at least twice

Tags: sql

In the attendance column in the ChildProgram relation, there are 1s and 0s which represents present and absent respectively. How do I select students that are absent for at least 2 times? (for this case, Hannah and Joash). The students who are selected will be displayed in an "email message".

[image: ChildProgram relation]

[image: This is the output of what is needed]

```
SELECT DISTINCT Concat('Dear Mr and/or Mrs ', C.lastname, 
                ', we are writing concerning your child’s attendance. ', 
                C.firstname, ' was absent from the subject ', CP.programid, 
                ' for at least 2 lessons.') 'Content of Email' 
FROM   child C, 
       childprogram CP 
WHERE  C.firstname = CP.firstname
```

Comment: use `COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: On a sidenote: Is `'Content of Email'` supposed to be a name for the result column? Single quotes delimit string literals, not names. Use double quotes in standard SQL or better avoid them completely: `AS content_of_email`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP_BY HAVING` for this.

```
SELECT C.EMAIL, C.LAST_NAME, C.FIRST_NAME, COUNT(*) as DAYS_OFF
FROM CHILD C
JOIN CHILDPROGRAM CP
ON C.FIRSTNAME = CP.FIRSTNAME
WHERE ATTENDANCE = 0
GROUP BY C.LAST_NAME, C.FIRST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Obviously change the select however you want, but this will give you the name and number of days they were absent, and only include children who were absent more than one day.

On a different note, using FIRSTNAME as your key for the child has obvious issues (you can't handle 2 children with the same name). I'm not sure how much control you have but probably a combination of the email and first name would work better. It would mean having EMAIL on CHILDPROGRAM table as well. That or just create an Id field you can use as a foreign key.